# maven-jarsigner not executing during build

Tags: java, android, maven, apk

everyone. I'm trying to sign an Android APK with Maven Jarsigner. I followed the instructions on the maven-jarsigner site and told it to use my own keystore and verify. It doesn't look like the jarsigner plugin is even running from my pom.xml, much less verifying. I'm using Codenvy as my environment right now, so Maven console commands are unavailable to me. Any help would be appreciated. Here's my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.kealinghornets.mapsapplication</groupId>
<artifactId>mobile-android-java-basic</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>apk</packaging>
<name>MapsApp</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <platform.version>4.1.1.4</platform.version>
    <android.plugin.version>3.8.0</android.plugin.version>
    <android.sdk.platform.version>20</android.sdk.platform.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <version>${platform.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jdroidframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-play-services</artifactId>
        <type>apklib</type>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>java</sourceDirectory>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jarsigner-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>sign</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>sign</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>                       
                    <execution>
                        <id>verify</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                     <keystore>${project.basedir}/mapsapp.keystore</keystore>
                     <storepass>maps_app</storepass>
                     <keypass>maps_app</keypass>
                     <alias>maps_app</alias>
                     <verbose>true</verbose>
                     <certs>true</certs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${android.plugin.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <sign>
                        <debug>false</debug>
                    </sign>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <sdk>
                    <platform>${android.sdk.platform.version}</platform>
                </sdk>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Here's my Maven output from the build:

```
[INFO] Injecting source code into builder...
[INFO] Source code injection finished
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building MapsApp 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ mobile-android-java-basic ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- android-maven-plugin:3.8.0:generate-sources (default-generate-sources) @ mobile-android-java-basic ---
[DEBUG] Expanding: /home/codenvy/.m2/repository/com/jdroidframework/google-play-services/0.6.0/google-play-services-0.6.0.apklib into /media/ephemeral1/builder/maven/builds/build-4794906119007517519/androidmaps/target/unpack/apklibs/com.jdroidframework_google-play-services_apklib_0.6.0
[DEBUG] expand complete
[INFO] ANDROID-904-002: Found aidl files: Count = 0
[INFO] ANDROID-904-002: Found aidl files: Count = 0
[INFO] ANDROID-904-002: Found aidl files: Count = 0
[INFO] Manifest merging disabled. Using project manifest only
[INFO] /usr/local/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/21.1.1/aapt [package, -m, -J, /media/ephemeral1/builder/maven/builds/build-4794906119007517519/androidmaps/target/generated-sources/r, -M, /media/ephemeral1/builder/maven/builds/build-4794906119007517519/androidmaps/AndroidManifest.xml, -S, /media/ephemeral1/builder/maven/builds/build-4794906119007517519/androidmaps/res, -S, /media/ephemeral1/builder/maven/builds/build-4794906119007517519/androidmaps/target/unpack/apklibs/com.jdroidframework_google-play-services_apklib_0.6.0/res, --auto-add-overlay, -I, /usr/local/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-20/android.jar]
[INFO] /usr/local/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/21.1.1/aapt [package, --non-constant-id, -m, -J, /media/ephemeral1/builder/maven/builds/build-4794906119007517519/androidmaps/target/generated-sources/r, --custom-package, com.google.android.gms, -M, /media/ephemeral1/builder/maven/builds/build-4794906119007517519/androidmaps/AndroidManifest.xml, -S, /media/ephemeral1/builder/maven/builds/build-4794906119007517519/androidmaps/res, -S, /media/ephemeral1/builder/maven/builds/build-4794906119007517519/androidmaps/target/unpack/apklibs/com.jdroidframework_google-play-services_apklib_0.6.0/res, --auto-add-overlay, -I, /usr/local/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-20/android.jar]
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:resources (default-resources) @ mobile-android-java-basic ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /media/ephemeral1/builder/maven/builds/build-4794906119007517519/androidmaps/src/main/resources
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /media/ephemeral1/builder/maven/builds/build-4794906119007517519/androidmaps/target/generated-sources/extracted-dependencies/src/main/resources
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /media/ephemeral1/builder/maven/builds/build-4794906119007517519/androidmaps/target/unpack/apklibs/com.jdroidframework_google-play-services_apklib_0.6.0/src
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- android-maven-plugin:3.8.0:consume-aar (default-consume-aar) @ mobile-android-java-basic ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:compile (default-compile) @ mobile-android-java-basic ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 5 source files to /media/ephemeral1/builder/maven/builds/build-4794906119007517519/androidmaps/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- android-maven-plugin:3.8.0:proguard (default-proguard) @ mobile-android-java-basic ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:testResources (default-testResources) @ mobile-android-java-basic ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /media/ephemeral1/builder/maven/builds/build-4794906119007517519/androidmaps/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ mobile-android-java-basic ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) @ mobile-android-java-basic ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- android-maven-plugin:3.8.0:emma (default-emma) @ mobile-android-java-basic ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- android-maven-plugin:3.8.0:dex (default-dex) @ mobile-android-java-basic ---
[INFO] /usr/local/jdk1.7.0_71/jre/bin/java [-Xmx1024M, -jar, /usr/local/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/21.1.1/lib/dx.jar, --dex, --output=/media/ephemeral1/builder/maven/builds/build-4794906119007517519/androidmaps/target/classes.dex, /media/ephemeral1/builder/maven/builds/build-4794906119007517519/androidmaps/target/classes, /home/codenvy/.m2/repository/com/jdroidframework/google-play-services/0.6.0/google-play-services-0.6.0.apklib, /home/codenvy/.m2/repository/android/google-play-services/r21/google-play-services-r21.jar, /home/codenvy/.m2/repository/com/google/android/support-v4/r7/support-v4-r7.jar]
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.5:jar (default-jar) @ mobile-android-java-basic ---
[INFO] Building jar: /media/ephemeral1/builder/maven/builds/build-4794906119007517519/androidmaps/target/mobile-android-java-basic.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- android-maven-plugin:3.8.0:apk (default-apk) @ mobile-android-java-basic ---
[INFO] Enabling debug build for apk.
[INFO] /usr/local/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/21.1.1/aapt [package, -f, -M, /media/ephemeral1/builder/maven/builds/build-4794906119007517519/androidmaps/AndroidManifest.xml, -S, /media/ephemeral1/builder/maven/builds/build-4794906119007517519/androidmaps/res, -S, /media/ephemeral1/builder/maven/builds/build-4794906119007517519/androidmaps/target/unpack/apklibs/com.jdroidframework_google-play-services_apklib_0.6.0/res, --auto-add-overlay, -I, /usr/local/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-20/android.jar, -F, /media/ephemeral1/builder/maven/builds/build-4794906119007517519/androidmaps/target/mobile-android-java-basic.ap_, --debug-mode]
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- android-maven-plugin:3.8.0:internal-pre-integration-test (default-internal-pre-integration-test) @ mobile-android-java-basic ---
[INFO] No InstrumentationRunner found - skipping tests
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- android-maven-plugin:3.8.0:internal-integration-test (default-internal-integration-test) @ mobile-android-java-basic ---
[INFO] No InstrumentationRunner found - skipping tests
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ mobile-android-java-basic ---
[INFO] Installing /media/ephemeral1/builder/maven/builds/build-4794906119007517519/androidmaps/target/mobile-android-java-basic.apk to /home/codenvy/.m2/repository/org/kealinghornets/mapsapplication/mobile-android-java-basic/1.0-SNAPSHOT/mobile-android-java-basic-1.0-SNAPSHOT.apk
[INFO] Installing /media/ephemeral1/builder/maven/builds/build-4794906119007517519/androidmaps/pom.xml to /home/codenvy/.m2/repository/org/kealinghornets/mapsapplication/mobile-android-java-basic/1.0-SNAPSHOT/mobile-android-java-basic-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] Installing /media/ephemeral1/builder/maven/builds/build-4794906119007517519/androidmaps/target/mobile-android-java-basic.jar to /home/codenvy/.m2/repository/org/kealinghornets/mapsapplication/mobile-android-java-basic/1.0-SNAPSHOT/mobile-android-java-basic-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 21.161s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Feb 26 19:57:09 UTC 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 22M/398M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Project androidmaps successfully build
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `maven-jarsigner-plugin` is declared inside `pluginManagement` section, so it will not be executed. [`pluginManagement`](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugin_Management) is only supposed to be used to factor configuration on a plugin for different Maven modules.

Note that the `android-maven-plugin` is in fact executed because it it also declared inside the `plugins` section, so it inherits from the declaration made in `pluginManagement`.

You should move the `maven-jarsigner-plugin` code into the `plugins` section.